# angular upload component, set min and max uploaded file size

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, file-upload

I'm working on a upload file component that will send the file through nodejs, but I have a problem with file size because if the file if bigger than few kb I receive this error:

```
Error: request entity too large (from nodejs)
[HTTP/1.1 413 Payload Too Large 7ms] (on browser console).
```

The upload component is created on frontend with angular and I need a solution on frontend to set the min and max file size.

[here is a fiddle with the angular component.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/5383/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use directive to get file size

```
    app.directive('checkFileSize', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      function bindEvent(element, type, handler) {
        if (element.addEventListener) {
          element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
        } else {
          element.attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
        }
      }

      bindEvent(elem[0], 'change', function() {
        alert('File size:' + this.files[0].size);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Another way is to get file size when sending to server like

```
uploader = new FileUploader();
uploader.filters.push({
    'name': 'enforceMaxFileSize',
    'fn': function (item) {
        return item.size <= 10485760; // 10 MiB to bytes
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/5392/)

Comment: can you put that in fiddle example to see if it's working ?

Comment: yes, the first part looks interesting but is only checking the file size and not set, the second example is part of "angular-file-upload" library.